# Query design with Sangria to prevent overhead

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have a question regarding schema/queries design.

Lets assume that there is a `Study` model.

`Study` can have multiple successors, so there is obviously `parentId` field.

```
case class Study(id: StudyId, name: String, parentId: Option[StudyId])
```

`User` from context can have access to studies, so we want to return all accessible studies as a tree to UI.
So the query field can be something like this

```
Field(name = "accessibleStudies", 
      fieldType = ListType(StudyNode.Type), 
      resolve = implicit ctx => inject[StudyQueries].accessibleStudies(ctx))
```

in the `accessibleStudies` method we ask DB for data and prepare list that can be viewed on UI as a tree.

```
class StudyQueries {
    def accessibleStudies(ctx: Ctx): Future[Seq[StudyNode]] = {
        // 50 lines of data fetching and transformation
    }
}
```

And now interesting part.
`StudyNode` should have additional field - `progress`, which can be calculated as a recursive sum of all successors' progresses, so we need *whole* accessible studies list everytime to get `progress` for *single* node.
So simple approach like

```
case class StudyNode(entity: Study)

object StudyNode {
    val Type = ObjectType[Ctx, StudyNode](
        ...
        Field(name = "progress",
              fieldType = ProgressType, 
              resolve = implicit ctx => inject[ProgressService].progressOfStudy(...))
    )
}
```

will lead to huge overhead, because we will need to get accessible studies again and again for every node. 
However, it seems to be convenient to calc progresses inside `StudyQueries.accessibleStudies`, so we will have something like prepared `Map[EntityId, Progress]`
And `StudyNode` definition now can be modified like this

```
case class StudyNode(entity: Study,
                     progresses: Map[EntityId, Progress])

object StudyNode {
    val Type = ObjectType[Ctx, StudyNode](
        ...
        Field(name = "progress", 
              fieldType = ProgressType, 
              resolve = implicit ctx => progresses(ctx.value.entity.getId))
    )
}
```

But it doesn't look like a clean solution for me.
Additionally I'll have to manually check `ctx.astFields` to verify that `progress` field is being called.
Now I wonder if there is better approach to handle situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Deferred Resolvers` / `Fetchers` which are able to cache the results during query execution for the same ids, so you no need to ask database twice...

More about this:
https://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#high-level-fetch-api
https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-scala/4-deferred_resolvers/

Additionally you can use any 3rd party library for more effective fetching like

http://47deg.github.io/fetch/ or
https://github.com/getclump/clump

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to avoid the N+1 Queries. 
Here is how you can overcome it:

1. Get the list of progress by multiple IDs.
   `def progresses(ids: Seq[EntityId])`
2. Now, you can use `Deferred` provided by Sangria to resolve the `StudyNode`, and use `groupBy` by EntityId.

`case class ProgressDeferred(entityId: EntityId) extends Deferred[Seq[Progress]]`

```
class ProgressResolver extends DeferredResolver[YourContext] {
  override def resolve(deferred: Vector[Deferred[Any]], ctx: YourContext, queryState: Any)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Vector[Future[Any]] = {
    val entityIds = deferred.map{
      case ProgressDeferred(entityId) => entityId
    }
    val progresses = ctx.progressService.progresses(entityIds).map(_.groupBy(_. entityId))

    entityIds.map(id=> progresses.map(_.get(id)))
  }
}
```